# File not accessing from cross server

Tags: php, curl

here is my test file URl:
http://saludganadora.com/newapp/test.php

When I run it in browser it works.
but When I try to access this from from crosse server by Curl it does not allow permission to access the file.
Here is the second URL in which I curl on above URL
http://ror.ranksol.com/abdullah/php/curl.php

here is my curl code:

```
<?php
function curl($url)
{
set_time_limit(0);
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); // here it sais to curl to just save it
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$data = curl_exec($ch);//get curl response
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}

$url = 'http://saludganadora.com/newapp/test.php';

echo curl($url);
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a CORS issue.

Add

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

to the top of test.php (before ANYTHING else).

If you can configure the server, then it should be easy to fix for all of your scripts.
See http://enable-cors.org/ for instructions on your particular server.